# Is there any standard terminology for this property?

Tags: functions, terminology, functional-equations

Let $f$ be a map whose domain is $X$. If $f$ satisfies the property that for all $x\in X$, $$f(f(x))=f(x)\text{,}$$ is there any standard name for such a function? Not sure if "projection" is the answer.

Comment: @MRK, it is not the identity function. Consider $f(x)=|x|$.

Comment: You should probably accept one of the answers, if you're satisfied with them.

Comment: @Nishant, yours is correct but it seems to me that the other answer is equally correct and provides more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called an [idempotent map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). More generally, one can talk about idempotent elements: given a set $S$ with a binary operator $*: S \times S \to S$, an element $x \in S$ is called *idempotent* if $x * x = x$. (Idempotent maps are idempotent elements in the [endomorphism monoid](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/endomorphism) of some object.)

In linear algebra, idempotent linear operators on a vector space are sometimes called "projections" or "[projectors](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/projector)".

Answer (score 3):

I think the term for that would be "idempotent."

Comment: That's the term I am looking for! How about "projection"? Is it also defined using the same property?

Comment: "Projections" are usually special cases of idempotent maps. I think usually, a projection $\pi: X\to Y$ is defined so that $f(y)=y$ for all $y\in Y$ (assuming here that $Y\subseteq X$).